# Monit sytax error in monitrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, monitoring, monit

I have the following mail-server setup in my monitrc file (version 5.6):

set mailserver smtp.gmail.com port 587
    username "myemail@gmail.com" password "mypassword"
    using tlsv1
    with timeout 30 seconds
    using hostname "mydomain.com"

(I sanitized the info of course)

When I try to start monit I am receiving the following error:

/etc/monit/monitrc:60: Error: syntax error 'timeout'

Line 60 is the line with the timeout statement. I cannot see anything wrong. Has anybody sen this error or have any idea what may be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to your timeout line mostly you use timeout like this for smtp

set mailserver mail.tildeslash.com, mail.foo.bar port 25
     username "Rabbi" password "Loew" using tlsv1, localhost
     with timeout 15 seconds

Try to apply in your case timeout error would be gone.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker